# Use linq to sort on changed field

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query using C# and would like to sort on a changed field. The field is a partial date field defined in the table as YYYYMM. However, I want it displayed in my repeater as, 
MM/YYYY but need to sort it as YYYYMM. Below is the code and GrantMonthID is the field in question. The repeater displays the data in MM/YYYY order.

Thank you.

```
var linqQuery = from nn in grantsReceivedDetailList
                           where (nn.ArrearAuditID == Convert.ToInt32(AdminBasePage.ArrearAuditId))
                            select
                            new
                            {
                                nn.GrantsReceivedID,
                                nn.PayeeMPINumber,
                                Firstname =     participantRepository.GetParticipantDetailsbyMemberParticipantIndex(Convert.ToInt32(nn.PayeeMPINumber)).FirstName + " " +
                                participantRepository.GetParticipantDetailsbyMemberParticipantIndex(Convert.ToInt32(nn.PayeeMPINumber)).LastName,
                                nn.IVANumber,
                                GrantMonthID = nn.GrantMonthID.ToString().Substring(4, 2) + "/" +                                              nn.GrantMonthID.ToString().Substring(0, 4),
                                nn.GrantAmount,
                                nn.Comments
                            };

            linqQuery = linqQuery.OrderByDescending(y => y.GrantMonthID);  
            // Execute the linq query and databind
            grantListRepeater.DataSource = linqQuery;
            grantListRepeater.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your anonymous type field which will contain original database date:

```
var linqQuery = 
    from nn in grantsReceivedDetailList
    where (nn.ArrearAuditID == Convert.ToInt32(AdminBasePage.ArrearAuditId))
    select new {
       nn.GrantsReceivedID,
       nn.PayeeMPINumber,
       Firstname = participantRepository.GetParticipantDetailsbyMemberParticipantIndex(Convert.ToInt32(nn.PayeeMPINumber)).FirstName + " " +
                   participantRepository.GetParticipantDetailsbyMemberParticipantIndex(Convert.ToInt32(nn.PayeeMPINumber)).LastName,
       nn.IVANumber,
       GrantMonthID = nn.GrantMonthID.ToString().Substring(4, 2) + "/" +          
                      nn.GrantMonthID.ToString().Substring(0, 4),
       nn.GrantAmount,
       nn.Comments,
       GrantMonthIdOriginal = nn.GrantMonthID // this field
    };
```

And sort by this field:

```
linqQuery = linqQuery.OrderByDescending(y => y.GrantMonthIdOriginal);

grantListRepeater.DataSource = linqQuery;
grantListRepeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: Works like a charm. This site(and you) rock.

Comment: I spoke to soon, sorry. This code change still displays in MM/YYYY order. I need YYYYMM order.  thx

Comment: @KentE nope, if you still have MM/YYYY order, then you are selecting wrong filed in OrderByDescending operator

Comment: Right you are. Too many hours doing this stuff. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Just create a property to sort on, and a property to bind to:

```
var query = from x in someList
            select new
            {
                SortField = FormatForSort(x.Field),
                DisplayField = FormatForDisplay(x.Field)
            };

query = query.OrderBy(x => x.SortField);
```

Alternately, select it by the Date, and format it how you want in the repeater instead of using LINQ since this is more of a View concern.

Comment: spoke to soon, sorry. This code change still displays in MM/YYYY order. I need YYYYMM order. Can you elaborate on the phrase: